# email validation with angular 6 works without the dot

Tags: angular

I'm working on an email validation which is working fine. But the issue is when the user fails to input a dot `.`, it checks as valid and if a user inputs three characters after the `@` sign without the dot ., it stills valid, how do I ensure that after the `@` sign there is a character and also after the character, there is a dot `.`

```
this.reportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  fullName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')])],
  telePhone: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Even with something like this `dd@fff` it tells you its valid

```
<ion-item style="color:red; background-color: white" *ngIf="!reportForm.controls.email.valid && email">
  Email not valid
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Do you not trust the [built-in email validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#email)?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: Also keep in mind that it is possible to have a valid email with no dot. Manual email validation is always a dangerous game.

Answer (score 2):

I have used below pattern for email validation. This pattern will check dot and it is worked for me. You may try it.

**Pattern:**

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: This pattern is not suitable for modern domains, like: anas@domain.store

Comment: @AnasSafi you can update the amount the character. Replace `{2,4}$` to `{2,5}$`

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is a meta-character in regular expressions.  It will match any alphanumeric character.
To match the literal `.` character, you will need to escape it with `\`.

Assuming you also intended to match the literal `.` character throughout your expression, the pattern string should be : `'^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the pattern below to work in Angular 6+. Keep in mind that no one regex expression is perfect for email validation. It comes down to what you want to exclude and what you want to include. The pattern below allows for basic Latin characters without any RFC 5322-allowed special characters. It makes sure there is an "@" and a "." in the email and allows for top-level domain extensions that are between 2 and 10 characters. For example, this will include domains that end in ".accountant", but not ".accountants".

This article can give you a great overview on the subject, with more examples - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s01.html

**Pattern:**

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,10}$
```

Comment: You need to add A-Z to this regex to accept email like: Anas@Gmail.com, as  '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'

Comment: the double slash before the dot was causing me problems.